# Runtime "syntax error" from lex and yacc

Tags: syntax-error, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I cannot figure out why I am getting these results.

```
++
+add
+syntax error 2

++
+add
+syntax error 4
```

The ++ is my input and lex echoes each character and yacc prints add whenever it gets a +. It's giving me this error on every other + it gets. Doesn't matter how I give the input, I get the same results if I hit enter on every +.

lex

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"

int chars = 0;
%}
%%
"+"     {ECHO; chars++; return ADD;}
.       {ECHO; chars++;}
\n      {ECHO;}
%%
```

yacc

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
extern int chars;

void yyerror (const char *str) {
    printf ("%s %d\n", str, chars);
}
%}

%token ADD
%%
symbol  : ADD       {printf ("add\n");}
        ;
%%

int main () {
    while (1) {
        yyparse ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar only accepts a 'sentence' that consists of a single token, `+`.  When you type a second `+`, you induce a syntax error; your grammar doesn't allow ADD followed by ADD.  Your next token after the `+` must be EOF for the grammar to accept your input.  (Because of the `.` and `\n` rules, you can type all sorts of other stuff at the code, but there can only be one `+` in the input.)